# Windows 8.1 mouse-clicks do not work on one particular user

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, mouse, debug, mouse-click

I was logged onto User1. I put my laptop from *[[cf.]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYrdX.png)* high-power mode to low-power mode, <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, and stuffed it into my bag.

Few hours later I typed in the password and resumed User1, and after lagging for many minutes the laptop is working per usual.

**However**, mouse-clicks and touchpad-clicks do not work. The cursor can move but clicking does nothing at all.

Everything else is per usual aside from being unable to click. I can still browse the internet and use programs using keyboard shortcuts and etc.

I've tried random stuff to fix it but none of these work:

- hibernate and unhibernate
- login other users
- disable and enable touchpad
- disable and enable mouse
- kill `dwm.exe`
- restart `explorer.exe`
- reinstall touchpad drivers (it requires a restart, so currently my touchpad doesn't work and is "pending a restart")
- logout other user
- remove mouse-usb, hibernate, unhibernate, then plugin mouse-usb

The laptop can't be restarted because there are important processes running whose state cannot be saved.

**Any ideas** what may be causing the problem and what can be done to fix it?

Update: now even moving the mouse has a "draw lag" problem **while** I'm logged onto User1. The cursor image is being drawn very slowly with "lag" artifacts. (Initially there wasn't this issue.)

---

Currently I'm posting this question using another user account. Miraculously the mouse and touchpad has problems on User1 but works fine on every other user account including the lock screen.

Comment: Restarting is the only way to solve your problem

Comment: What happens if you connect an external mouse? Maybe try uninstalling the driver? Just a guess. Maybe try hybernating and starting the computer back up? This could reinitialize the device without losing state of the program.

Comment: @IanM, The mouse is an external usb mouse.. or do you mean something else? I've edited the question with the following information: I've tried hibernating and unhibernating but it doesn't work. I've [disabled and re-enabled](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FPqwz.png) the mouse and the touchpad too. Also, I've uninstalled the touchpad and reinstalled it (but for the reinstall to be "complete" a restart is required. so currently my touchpad doesn't work and my devmgmt.msc doesn't show my touchpad as it is uninstalled and pending a restart.)

Comment: Note that the mouse works fine in the other users and on the main windows "lock" screen. It only doesn't work in User1. I suspect a windows bug happened and ended up having a process in my User1 trapping all the mouseclicks, so while the cursor is able to move, clicks do not work in User1.